# RESPONSIVE Hero image not sizing down (iPhone)

Tags: responsive-design

Everything looks fine on desktop/iPad, but look on iPhone and the "hero" image isn't sizing down. Not very good with responsive design to begin with, but it is driving me crazy. [Here is link](http://leveragingmanufacturing.com)

I would really appreciate the help!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a set height on `.da-slider`. You will need to use media queries at the widths that you wish the height to change and explicitly state them.